# How to move server(Express - MERN) to sub directory and work on Heroku

Tags: javascript, express, heroku, mern

I have a MERN stack project where previously everything server related was at the root level, however issues with ESLINT, VSCODE and package.json files has meant that I'm moving everything related to the server into it own sub directory.

However this has meant that Heroku is now giving me errors that look related to Express not being able to serve the files. Please see screengrab of errors on Heroku log below.

Deploying the app on Heroku works fine with no build errors.

[image]

How Express is configured in my server.js file

```
// prod only, uses /public in dev env
app.use(express.static('index.html', { root: '../client/build' }) );

app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(`index.html`, { root: '../client/build' });
});
```

My directory structure

```
client/
   src/
   public/
   build/
   package.json
server/
   routes/
   models/
   server.js
   package.json
.gitignore
README.md
package.json // very small file only including scripts to satisfy Heroku
```

Root level package.json (entire contents of file)

```
{
"scripts": {
    "start": "cd server && node server.js",
    "build": "cd client && npm run build",
    "install-server": "cd server && npm install",
    "install-client": "cd client && npm install",
    "heroku-postbuild": "npm run install-server && npm run install-client && npm run build"
    }
}
```

Notes:

1. Express isn't having a problem serving the files when I start the project locally
2. Heroku requires a package.json file at the root directory if you're suing a Node.js type project. This is why I have a small package.json in my root that doesn't have much in it

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out switching from this:

```
app.use(express.static('index.html', { root: '../client/build' }) );
```

To

```
app.use(express.static('/app/client/build'))
```

Solved the issue.

I did try `app.use(express.static('index.html', { root: '/app/client/build' }) );` but that again broke the site.